# Dismiss Image Picker before upload

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

So I am uploading a user's image to my server. I have the following code for once a user selects an image in the `UIImagePickerController`:

```
    public void Picked(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("done picking");
        picker.DismissViewController (false, null);

        image.Image = e.Info [UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;


        UploadImage (); //call the upload function
    }
```

This works except I want the picker to be dismissed before the `UploadImage();` call but it isn't being dismissed until after the upload completes.

How can I get the picker view to dismiss immediately upon selecting an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the view to update I called `UplodImage()` from a new thread

```
Thread t = new Thread (UploadImage);
t.Start ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you run UploadImage via dispatchAsync like this:

```
   public void Picked(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("done picking");
        picker.DismissViewController (false, null);

        image.Image = e.Info [UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;

        yourQueue = new DispatchQueue ("Image Uploading Queue");
        yourQueue.DispatchAsync (() => {

             UploadImage (); //call the upload function
        });
    }
```

that way your UI can update.

Comment: it wont compile, do I need a `using` directive?

Comment: What namespace is `DispatchQueue` in?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your uploadImage in GCD.

Something like this:

```
picker.DismissViewController (false, null);
image.Image = e.Info [UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;

dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0); 

dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

    uploadImage();
});
```